# Php facebook webdriver (selenium) doesn't work on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: php, selenium

any simple project doesn't work on server. In log file i see session  error. Php and selenium with facebook webdriver.

Comment: Can you show a simple code example that fails along with any messages it generates.

Comment: I agree with @NigelRen. You should read the [Stackoverflow question guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please go through [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It may be worth deleting this question now you have asked a new one.

Answer (score 0):

get('https://fa.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D9%88%D8%A8%DA%AF%D8%A7%D9%87');
$result = $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('firstHeading')) // find search input element
    ->getText(); // fill the search box
echo $result;

$driver->quit();

?>